# Deferred calculations in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Suppose I have some service S that receives requests from client C. 
S cannot response immediately due to heavy calculations, C also cannot wait until forever and has his own timeout period.

My idea is to implement the server side as described here: 
[REST and long running jobs, Farazdagi](http://farazdagi.com/blog/2014/rest-long-running-jobs/)

In my ServerController I have a thread pool for deferred calculations and a concurrent map to store responses.

```
private final int NUMBER_OF_WORKERS = 10;
private Map<String, ResponseEntity<MathResponse>> responseMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_WORKERS);
```

My `/calculate` mapping submits jobs to the thread pool and returns with `202 (Accepted)` HTTP status and puts redirection link to `Location` header.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calculate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> startWorkflow(@RequestBody MathRequest request, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        // time-consuming calculations here
        ResponseEntity<MathResponse>response = HardMath.execute(request)
        responseMap.put(uuid.toString(), response);
    });

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    UriComponents uriComponents = builder.path("/wf/queue/{id}").buildAndExpand(uuid.toString());
    headers.setLocation(uriComponents.toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

In `/queue/id` mapping I return result if it's in the map:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/queue/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<MathResponse> getQueueInfo(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    ResponseEntity<MathResponse> defaultQueueResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(new MathResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
    return responseMap.getOrDefault(id, defaultQueueResponse);
}
```

I suppose that using such low-level things like `ConcurrentHashMap` is not a good idea. Are there any options in Spring that I could use instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Looks like your map is never cleared. Could be a memory leak here. Actually you can use any storage - in memory DB or queue where result is also message with serialized response.

Comment: Yes, I know about that. I just wanted to explain the idea and show some moments that I'm not confident with.

Comment: Do you think that everything else is applicable?

Comment: For me the logic is fine but result storage should be different. Actually it depends on result size. Storing to DB (e.g. H2) or key/value storage (e.g. Redis) requires serialize/deserialize the objects. If amount of results and result size is not big the Map is fine.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the question of resilience; if the results are local to an instance of S (i.e. in an in-process Map) then if that instance of S crashes or is restarted then the results are lost and C would be forced to resubmit its request(s). If the results cache within S was backed by a resilient store then the results could survive a crash/restart of S.

Spring's [caching abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) with a backing store of <*insert storage technology here*> could help.